# How do I programmatically add NewLines to a TFS work item textbox?

Tags: c#, tfs, newline, tfs-workitem

I have a web system that has a few hooks into our TFS work item system.  One of the things I am trying to do is that when a certain action is performed, it takes the current text in one field and makes a comment in the "General Comments" field announcing what the field was previously (Yes I know, history contains this but the higher ups want this in the gen comments).

The problem I am having is that TFS seems to be ignoring Environment.NewLines that I have in my string.  So with this code:

```
                    item.Fields[GENCOMMENTS].Value = string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                                , " - QA Dashboard - Required By Date Reason set to \"Hotfix\", but previously contained \""
                                , item.Fields[REQBYDTREASON].Value.ToString()
                                , "\"."
                                , Environment.NewLine
                                , Environment.NewLine
                                , Environment.NewLine
                                , item.Fields[GENCOMMENTS].Value.ToString());
```

So assuming my general comments section contains:

```
THIS SENTENCE WAS ALREADY IN GENERAL COMMENTS
```

I get the following output in the general comments section when the work item is saved

```
9/29/2010 - QA Dashboard - Required By Date Reason set to "Hotfix", but previously contained "hotfixtest".THIS SENTENCE WAS ALREADY IN GENERAL COMMENTS
```

Why is it ignoring the new lines and how can I get a new line into the work item?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TFS work item content is often processed as HTML.  That's likely happening here and hence it's ignoring the extraneous newlines in the text.  Try wrapping the content in a `<pre>` block or using `<p>` and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

RTF or HTMl controls will use and render html markup - so depends on the control. Try adding and formatting rich text to a multiline control and then debug it in a console app - browse the field value - you'll see html tags.

Comment: hence, you'll at least need <br> if this is the case, white space and \n will be ignored by an html rtf control.